# Let $\sigma\in S_n$. Show that $\sigma(1\:2\:\dots\:n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\:\sigma(2)\:\dots\:\sigma(n))$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I have no idea how to show this as cycle notation really confuses me.

Comment: before showing something it would be useful to convince your self that this could possibly be true i.e., by checking out some examples.... you tried that way? you would see some pattern and then try making some general sense out of it... try this $(1234)(123456)(1432)$...

Answer (score 2):

Let's work this through.

We start with $\sigma(1)$ and apply $\sigma^{-1}$ which gets us to $1$

Then we apply $(1 2 \cdots n)$ which takes $1$ to $2$

Then we apply $\sigma$ to $2$ which takes us to $\sigma(2)$

So the permutation on the left-hand side takes $\sigma(1)$ to $\sigma(2)$. Just show that this works for some general $r$ and that $\sigma(n)$ goes to the right place.

Comment: Perhaps also mention why for $k\notin \{ \sigma(1),\dotsc,\sigma(n)\}$ the conjugated cycle leaves $k$ fixed?

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed - but $\sigma \in S_n$ is given. I was going to put a note that the most confusing thing is whether the permutations are applied on the right or on the left, and getting things in the right order.